# Ruby on Rails: Inserting .js file in asset but still getting no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, typeerror

This maybe a long shot question to ask, but its worth a try...

I have a .js file that I inserted into my vendor/assets/javascript folder and then in my `application.js` in the apps/assets/javascript folder, I inserted the correct file name

```
//= require autoresize.jquery
```

The file name is `autoresize.jquery.js`I'm using the library from [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/).

In one of my .js.coffee script file I have this

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('textarea').autosize();
```

But I'm getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autosize'
```

I know that the jquery file is being loaded because I can see it in chrome's inspection element tool, and also, I have required jquery first. I'm just not understanding why I'm still getting that error?

Comment: Please show application.js

Comment: Putting files under vendor might require restarting rails?

Comment: What you did is right, the error may be raised by something else than what you think. Be that as it may, you could try the usual `rake assets:precompile` and if this works for you, consider taking a look at your assets configuration.

Comment: check the order of the assets, `autoresize.jquery` should appear before the files that require it in the `application.js` manifest.